# Internet Explorer does not load images cross domain

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-domain, imagesource, qualtrics

I am using Qualtrics to create a survey. In the survey I included pictures using html from a different website. It works in ALL browser but Internet Explorer 8 just doesn show pictures cross domain.

I am looking for html or javascript code to allow access for loading pictures from otehr domains...

thanks

Comment: Please show an example. There is no Single Oricin Policy for images

Comment: Are you trying to load an image under http to a page under https?

Answer (score 0):

Uh, if you have a page at http://www.example.com/foo.html, you should be able to put an image on that page like:

```
<img src="http://www.example.org/bar.jpg">
```

...just fine.

What do the links look like? What happens if you try to load that link directly in IE8's location bar?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to bet a beer that the image is a [CMYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) image, which IE can't render in any version.